# Why's "peu s'en faut" grammatical, when falloir must be preceded by "il"?

Tags: pronoms-impersonnels

Why isn't "peu s'en faut" preceded by il? Like "peu IL s'en faut"?

Doesn't this violate the rule that a dummy pronoun must precede "falloir"?

[image]

[peu s'en faut | WordReference Forums](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/peu-sen-faut.393107/)

> I don't find the English translation very good.
> *Peu s'en faut* (also said *il s'en faut de peu* as a whole sentence), says almost everything is going wrong, from the start to the end. It's worse than *very few happy things* in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider that *peu s'en faut* is a fixed phrase that deviates from the standard syntax rules (I have the feeling it is actually an archaic turn but cannot find any evidence to back this up).

Same eg for *tant s'en faut* or *point trop n'en faut*.

*Peu s'en faut* means that something almost happened. That is also the meaning in the exceprt you are refering too, from "La Vie de Galilée": it means "he's almost dead", "he is virtually dead".

EDIT: this [article](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/peu-s-en-faut-a147253824) (thank you Dimitris) confirms that the omission of the impersonal *il* is an archaic turn.

Comment: +1. I found a very interesting article here: http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/peu-s-en-faut-a147253824